# Multithreading Performance of JVM's Memory Allocator

Tags: java, multithreading, memory-management, jvm

I have a multi-threaded program that does heavy memory allocation. The performance is fine on a quad-core i7 CPU and the speed up is around 3.9X. But, when the program is executed on a 12-core Xeon CPU, the speedup value does not go beyond 5.5X.

I should mention that the GC seems not to be a problem because VisualGC reports below 1 seconds for GC after more than 100 seconds of execution. The main memory usage belongs to the Eden section of heap and other sections hardly get used. The code does massive int array allocations and performs some arithmetic operations on them. It is somehow like state-space exploring and allocation of new instances cannot be avoided.

As you know, the standard memory allocators of both Windows and Linux show unsatisfactory performance for multi-threaded programs and good alternatives like tcmalloc and Hoard are available for C/C++. Since the parallel section consists of fully independent tasks and the GC time is very low, I doubted that the main reason should be the bad performance of JVM's memory allocator when too many threads compete for allocation.

Does anybody have experience with JVM's allocator in massive multithreaded programs and can give advise on how I can overcome this problem??

P.S. I have tested the code using JVM 6,7, and 8. The allocation rate is also very high (around 10 millions per second) but as I mentioned the Eden section is heavily used and the working set is less than a Gigabyte.

Comment: I would start with profiling of an application.

Comment: I don't have anything to back this up, but I'm pretty sure the JVM requests large blocks of memory for each thread, and then each thread does the local allocations from that block. This should perform pretty well unless you're doing tons of allocations of huge objects. I'm sure someone more familiar with the JVM internals can give more details (or correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: @AndrewLogvinov I have profiled the code and as I mentioned, the overhead of GC is less than 1% and the code fully utilizes the cores in an i7 CPU.

Comment: @SaeedShahrivari are u expecting around 12X now ?

Comment: @Vipin Actually, not 12X but 5.5X is also not promising. Because, the code is totally computation intensive and the working set can totally fit in the cache.

Comment: @SaeedShahrivari then this is tuning problem. How many thread do you have for this computation ?

Comment: @Vipin I have tested various threads from 12 to 30 threads on a 12-core machine but the best case is 12 threads and performance slightly decreases with more threads.

Comment: @SaeedShahrivari its good you tested with some numbers , i would suggest try to test some numbers between 4 to 12 also may be we get some clue as i dont see any other options as of now.

Comment: I can hardly believe that JVM allocation is the bottleneck. Allocation from the heap is usually as fast as just bumping a pointer. There is no even need for atomic instructions since each thread has its own allocation buffer (TLAB). By the way, you can play with TLAB size using `-XX:TLABSize=NNN` JVM option and see if there is any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Is it the case that Eden space is less than what it should be in your case? If so, consider using 
-XX:NewRatio=1 or other appropriate value.

To ascertain that, please use 
-XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution
to see the distribution..